# "Partial" iPad Pro support?

Tags: ios, ipad

Would it be possible to have something like a "partial" Pro support? I am completely happy with how my upscaled game looks like on an iPad Pro and don't see the need to invest in yet another set of resources, but I would like to use or support other non-graphical features (like the new keyboard). Is introducing an according storyboard (which is BTW a bit peculiar way of having to define Pro support, as I don't use storyboards at all...) an all-or-nothing thing with being exposed to the large screen size then?

Comment: Added storyboard as launchimage (the only way I know to startup in iPad Pro mode) and found my graphics messed up since I can't handle the larger reported resolution (and as I said the effort is really not needed since the graphics are more than just ok when scaled up -- and I am normally really picky with that...).

Comment: See http://rombos.s3.amazonaws.com/Misc/iPadPro.png for the messed up main menu screen...

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? A competent answer to this completely valid question would be more helpful!